# How to child listview item can have data for each item

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview

I have two listviews, parent listview having item Essay which contains child listview of the "20 essay title". When Essay's title clicked on it open an activity which having text view to display text. I don't want to make 20 activity for 20 essays each. is there any way when I open any child item, it shows only specified data for that only that child item.
here is an example of pics

Parent list and Opened Descriptive Essay

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QksjP7hzpqmVCk_Y1ctwsDMYkijDHQPt/view?usp=sharing][1]

After clicked on Descriptive Essay. IT shows Child EssayTitle list

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NLbkrKD9c8yZb7rvapCxb-Na_lCVJf3P][2]

Now Click on Child List item Essay title "Call No Man Happy Till".it Shows full Answer

[https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1542uOZFzLx8vU7EMlsEhRaWZaguVTKHV
] [3]

I searched everywhere I don't know exactly what to do. Sorry, but I am new to android dev. I just have created a custom adapter and an array list

```
 public class Writing extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.formenuitem);


            ArrayList<MenuItems> essay = new ArrayList<>();



            ArrayList<MenuItems> items = new ArrayList<>();

            ArrayList<MenuItems> task2Item = new ArrayList<>();

            //================= main items
            items.add(new MenuItems("Descriptive Essay", "list of descriptive essay and solutions"));

            items.add(new MenuItems("Essay 1", "More Essay list"));

            items.add(new MenuItems("Type of Essay ", "How to start Essay Task 1, body-paragraph "));


            items.add(new MenuItems("Task 2", "Solved essay "));


   //show this list in when clicked on Descriotive essay item================================================================


            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Call No Man Happy Till","This essay about crime"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Education","This essay about Education"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("University","This essay about University"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Food","This essay about Food"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Games","This essay about crime"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Experience","This essay about crime"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("This is another essay","This essay about crime"));
            task2Item.add(new MenuItems("This is another essay","This essay about crime"));




    //======================set up for main item list
         final    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, items, R.color.category_numbers);


         //setting adapter to have task 2 list
            final ListAdapter task2list = new ListAdapter(Writing.this ,task2Item,R.color.category_numbers);

            //creating variable to find list view for both
          final  ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

          final ListView task2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // set up to click on the writing

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        if(position==0){
                            // make clickable at position 0

                            task2.setAdapter(task2list);

                            task2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    if (position==0){

                                        Intent open = new Intent(Writing.this,ContentDisplay.class);

                                        startActivity(open);


                                    }
                                }
                            });

                    }


                }
            });

        }
    }

I just when I open essay item it leads to me to an essay title list and when I click on essay title it shows me whole answer


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpgLL.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc4wx.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLqeg.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Custom Adapter. implement the onClick listener inside the adapter views. and for position, tag the adapter view and gets its tag within the listener.  I hope you are familiar with creating custom adapter.
In case you need more help, i hope to help.

Comment: thx for ur answer. and I have already tried but I got confused. with the data where should I store so I can reference its id in a  custom adapter. So when I click on each child list item, it opens different essays on each item. example.  Click the Descriptive Essay. After clicking on Descriptive Essay. It shows Child EssayTitles list then I see full essay

Comment: If its showing different items, tag the view in the adaper using the position, remember to convert it to string. Then later, get this tag from within the onclick listener using v.getTag() and use it to reference the item you need.

Comment: I have just got some idea what you are talking about. earlier I did this to have images in list item by the custom adapter. if I get stuck I will send u the full code bro